Create columns from grouped output
I have data which looks like this
startDate   endDate value   sourceName
0   2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00   2024-06-03 22:46:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch
6   2024-06-03 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:48:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  Connect
1   2024-06-03 22:46:00+02:00   2024-06-03 22:49:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake   AppleWatch
2   2024-06-03 22:49:00+02:00   2024-06-04 00:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM   AppleWatch
3   2024-06-04 00:56:00+02:00   2024-06-04 03:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch
4   2024-06-04 05:56:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM   AppleWatch
5   2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00   HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore  AppleWatch

I group them into "sleep sessions" by device and start end date if the gap is no larger than 2 hours like so.
                startDate                   endDate                     duration
sourceName              
AppleWatch  0   2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00   7.500000
            1   2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00   9.133333
Connect     1   2024-06-03 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:48:00+02:00   9.133333

I would like to get columns which sum the duration of each grouped value (within the session). example
REM_duration
Core_duration
Awake_duration

Also any gaps between stages (see between row index 3&4) should be added to Awake_duration. Example Awake_duration from session 0 should be 2.05
So expected output would be
    startDate                   endDate                    duration sourceName  rem_duration    core_duration   awake_duration
0   2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00   7.500000    AppleWatch  4.116667    3.333333    2.05
1   2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00   9.133333    AppleWatch  0.000000    9.133333    0.00
1   2024-06-03 22:40:00+02:00   2024-06-04 07:48:00+02:00   8.133333    Connect 1.000000    7.133333    1.00

This is what I have so far
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = [
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:26:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:46:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:46:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:49:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAwake",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:49:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 00:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 00:56:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 03:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 05:56:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 07:56:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepREM",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 22:40:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-05 07:48:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "AppleWatch"
    },
    {
        "startDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-03 22:40:00+0200"),
        "endDate": pd.Timestamp("2024-06-04 07:48:00+0200"),
        "value": "HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleepCore",
        "sourceName": "Connect"
    }
]

# Create DataFrame
df_orig = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data).sort_values('startDate')
max_gap = 2

df = df_orig.copy()

df = df.sort_values(['sourceName', 'startDate'])

df['duration'] = (df['endDate'] - df['startDate']).div(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))

g = df['startDate'].sub(df['endDate'].shift()).div(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
df2 = df.groupby(['sourceName', g.gt(max_gap).cumsum()]).agg({'startDate':'min', 'endDate':'max', 'duration': 'sum'})


Your expected output is unclear. Please be explicit, provide what the exact output should be and break down all computations

added the expected output

Thanks, it's a bit more explicit but not fully clear given your output. I don't get where the 1h is coming from in the last row, not why you have 8.133333 instead of 9.133333. If you clarify, it should be fairly easy to adapt the code below.

IIUC, you can add an extra grouper, an extra column with groupby.diff, the perform your custom computations, unstack and concat:
max_gap = 2

tmp = (df_orig
   .sort_values(['sourceName', 'startDate'])
   .assign(duration=lambda x: x['endDate'].sub(x['startDate']).div(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)),
           delta=lambda x: x['startDate'].sub(x.groupby('sourceName')['endDate'].shift())
                                         .div(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)),
           n=lambda x: x['delta'].gt(max_gap).cumsum(),
           col=lambda x: x['value'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+[a-z]*)$', expand=False).str.lower()
           
          )
   .groupby(['sourceName', 'n', 'col'])
   .agg({'startDate':'min', 'endDate':'max',
         'duration': 'sum', 'delta': 'sum'})
)

g = tmp.groupby(level=['sourceName', 'n'])

out = (pd.concat([g[['startDate']].min(), g[['endDate']].max(),
                  g[['duration']].sum(),
                  (tmp['duration'].mask((tmp.index.get_level_values('col')=='awake'),
                                        tmp['duration']+g['delta'].transform('sum')
                                       )
                   .unstack('col', fill_value=0)
                   .add_suffix('_duration')
                  )], axis=1)
         .reset_index(level=0).rename_axis(None)
      )

Output:
   sourceName                 startDate                   endDate  duration  awake_duration  core_duration  rem_duration
0  AppleWatch 2024-06-03 22:26:00+02:00 2024-06-04 07:56:00+02:00  7.500000            2.05       3.333333      4.116667
1  AppleWatch 2024-06-04 22:40:00+02:00 2024-06-05 07:48:00+02:00  9.133333            0.00       9.133333      0.000000
1     Connect 2024-06-03 22:40:00+02:00 2024-06-04 07:48:00+02:00  9.133333            0.00       9.133333      0.000000

